# How to filter obiee analysis but subtotal values?

Tags: oracle, analysis, obiee

In the analysis, I need to show all sold items for some period totals of which are bigger that some value let's say 100. When I apply this to item price it filters out items that have less price than given limit.  However they contain in that period and participate in forming subtotals.

For example:

```
Item    Price 
A       56 
B       102 
C       9 
D       247

Total   414
```

Here if I set filter price> 100 it would show only items B and D. What I want is to see all items that participate in making total of 414, that is I want to filter by totals. Is it possible in OBIEE??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Selection Steps which are applied after the execution of the query and hence do not cut off the data stream.

You would say "Keep Only Items having Price > 100".

Sherzodbek any reason why you post all your questions here rather than then Oracle forums?

Comment: Thank you, Chris for your answer! It worked after applying selection steps, it seems I havent cleary understood selection steps concept yet. I post here cause I am used to work in this platform more than in Oracle community, but I guess you are right with posting questions related to Oracle in community. I will take that into account. Thanks again!